# Highlight a Table Row when Mouseover HighChart Pie

Tags: jquery, highcharts

When I move mouse over the pie I can see the console.log writing to console. So I decided to add a code to highlight the table rows matching the pie.

```
mouseOver: function(e) {
   console.log(this.options.id);
   $(this).find('#tableId tr#this.options.id').toggleClass("hover");
},
mouseOut: function(e) {
   console.log(this.options.id);
   $(this).find('#tableId tr#this.options.id').toggleClass("hover");
},
.......
```

Have a table with `id="tableId`

```
<table id="tableId">
   <tr id="someMatchingName">
      <td>Hello</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I know this does not work. I have seen examples using `live` but that does not seems to match the need. Does anyone know what should I use to highlight the row when mouse over a pie and un-highlight when mouse out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's should be unique in HTML so you can write just

```
mouseOver: function(e) {
   console.log(this.options.id);
   $('#' + this.options.id).addClass("hover");
},
mouseOut: function(e) {
   console.log(this.options.id);
   $('#' + this.options.id).removeClass("hover");
},
.......
```

Comment: Static reference like `#id tr#trId` or `#trId` works but the dynamic reference as `# + this.options.id` does not work. I am positive these `id` don`t exists anywhere on the page. It should have worked but I don`t know why?

Comment: do you see anything in console? Based on the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.events) `this` is the [`Series`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series) object and that's what you want. Try dumping `this` to console.

Comment: Figured what the problem was. The `id` I was using had space, something like `My Id` and that caused the problem. Now its fixed after watching late night Wolverine.